# Is it possible to use the "findbyId" method in ingiteRepository?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ignite

I want to use IgniteRepository and query method.
The "save" method and "findAll" method is okay, but when I try to find data by id, I have trouble to use "findById" method.
Is it possible to use query method by ignite repository?
(Ignite cache uses Key-Value format. I also wonder the id at the "findById" in IgniteRepository, means whether key or @id in value.)

1. Following is error message.

   ```
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No fragment found for method public abstract java.util.Optional org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.findById(java.lang.Object)
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.lambda$null$2(RepositoryComposition.java:353) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
   at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryComposition.java:353) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
   at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:348) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:2.1.9.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy145.findById(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
   at kr.co.ignite.api.MyRestController.getDog(MyRestController.java:68) ~[classes/:na]
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_232]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_232]
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_232]
   ```
2. Following is Entity.

   ```
   import java.io.Serializable;
   import java.util.Date;

   import javax.persistence.Entity;
   import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
   import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
   import javax.persistence.Id;

   import org.apache.ignite.cache.query.annotations.QuerySqlField;

   import lombok.AccessLevel;
   import lombok.Data;
   import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
   import lombok.ToString;

   @NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
   @ToString
   @Data
   @Entity
   public class Dog implements Serializable {

       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

       @Id
       @QuerySqlField(index = true)
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
       private Long id;

       @QuerySqlField(index = true)
       private String name;

       @QuerySqlField(index = true)
       private Date birthday;
   }
   ```
3. Following is Repository witch extends IgniteRepository.

   ```
   import org.apache.ignite.springdata.repository.IgniteRepository;
   import org.apache.ignite.springdata.repository.config.RepositoryConfig;

   import kr.co.ignite.model.Dog;

   @RepositoryConfig(cacheName = "DogCache")
   public interface DogRepository extends IgniteRepository < Dog, Long > {
   }
   ```
4. Following is Ignite Configuration.

   ```
   import org.apache.ignite.Ignite;
   import org.apache.ignite.Ignition;
   import org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration;
   import org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration;
   import org.apache.ignite.springdata.repository.config.EnableIgniteRepositories;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
   import org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryLookupStrategy;

   import kr.co.ignite.model.Breed;
   import kr.co.ignite.model.Dog;
   import kr.co.ignite.repository.BreedRepository;
   import kr.co.ignite.repository.DogRepository;

   @Configuration
   @EnableIgniteRepositories(basePackageClasses = {BreedRepository.class, DogRepository.class},
   queryLookupStrategy = QueryLookupStrategy.Key.CREATE_IF_NOT_FOUND)
   public class SpringAppConfig {

       @Bean
       public Ignite igniteInstance() {
           IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

           // Setting some custom name for the node.
           cfg.setIgniteInstanceName("springDataNode");
           // Enabling peer-class loading feature.
           cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
           cfg.setLocalHost("127.0.0.1");


           // Defining and creating a new cache to be used by Ignite Spring Data
           // repository.
           CacheConfiguration<Long, Dog> ccfgDog = new CacheConfiguration<Long, Dog>("DogCache");
           CacheConfiguration<Long, Breed> ccfgBreed = new CacheConfiguration<Long, Breed>("BreedCache");
           // Setting SQL schema for the cache.
           ccfgBreed.setIndexedTypes(Long.class, Breed.class);
           ccfgDog.setIndexedTypes(Long.class, Dog.class);
           cfg.setCacheConfiguration(new CacheConfiguration[] { ccfgDog, ccfgBreed });

           return Ignition.start(cfg);
       }
   }
   ```
5. Following is Controller.

   ```
   import java.util.Date;

   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
   import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

   import kr.co.ignite.model.BeanUtil;
   import kr.co.ignite.model.Dog;
   import kr.co.ignite.model.UETenancy;
   import kr.co.ignite.repository.DogRepository;
   import kr.co.ignite.repository.TenancyRepository;


   @RestController
   @RequestMapping(value = "/api")
   public class MyRestController {

       private long increment = 0L;

       /* */
       @PostMapping(value = "/ignite")
       public ResponseEntity<String> addDog(@RequestBody Dog dog) throws Exception {

           DogRepository dogRepository = BeanUtil.getBean(DogRepository.class);

           dog.setId(increment);
           dog.setBirthday(new Date());

           dogRepository.save(increment++, dog);

           return ResponseEntity.ok().body("ok");
       }

       /* */
       @GetMapping(value = "/ignite")
       public ResponseEntity<Iterable<Dog>> getDogs() throws Exception {

           DogRepository dogRepository = BeanUtil.getBean(DogRepository.class);

           return ResponseEntity.ok().body(dogRepository.findAll());
       }

       /* */
       @GetMapping(value = "ignite/{id}")
       public ResponseEntity<Dog> getDog(@PathVariable long id) throws Exception {

           DogRepository dogRepository = BeanUtil.getBean(DogRepository.class);

           return ResponseEntity.ok().body(dogRepository.findById(id).get());
       }

       /* */
       @PutMapping(value = "/ignite/{id}")
      public ResponseEntity<Dog> editDog(@RequestBody Dog dog, @PathVariable long id) throws Exception {

           DogRepository dogRepository = BeanUtil.getBean(DogRepository.class);

           Dog dogToEdit = dogRepository.findById(id).get();
           dogToEdit.setName(dog.getName());
           dogToEdit.setBirthday(dog.getBirthday());
           return ResponseEntity.ok().body(dogRepository.findById(dogToEdit.getId()).get());
       }

       @DeleteMapping(value = "/ignite/{id}")
       public ResponseEntity<String> removeDog(@PathVariable long id) throws Exception {

           DogRepository dogRepository = BeanUtil.getBean(DogRepository.class);

           dogRepository.deleteById(id);

           return ResponseEntity.ok().body("ok");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Which version of Ignite are you using?

Comment: I'm using ignite version 2.8.0

Comment: Did u resolve this issue?

Comment: No, I just got to know that the ignite repository library didn't supported the "findById" query method yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes some of the methods are not supported yet. Please refer [this](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/extensions-and-integrations/spring/spring-data) and [this](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/tutorials/spring/spring-ignite-tutorial#develop-the-spring-rest-controller) links for more details.

But you can achieve all of them by making use of cache APIs along with IgniteRepository APIs like below,

```
@RequestMapping("/persons")
@RestController
public class PersonRestController {

    @Autowired
    private Ignite ignite;
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository ps;
    private IgniteCache<Integer, Person> personCache;

    @PostConstruct
    private void postConstruct() {
        personCache = ignite.cache("person-cache");
    }

    @GetMapping("/count")
    public Long count() {
        return ps.count();
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Iterable<Person> findAll() {
        return ps.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Person findById(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        return personCache.get(id);
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public boolean deleteById(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        return personCache.remove(id);
    }
    
}
```

Please refer [this](https://github.com/ashishb888/ignite-2.9-poc/tree/main/ignite-repositories-server) and [this](https://github.com/ashishb888/ignite-2.9-poc/tree/main/ignite-repositories-rest-client) links for complete working application source code

Thank you!